Xeokit TreeViewPlugin does not work with glb model
I try to render GLB file in xeokit viewer and toggle some of its elements with TreeViewPlugin. My HTML file looks like so:
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Model</title>
    <style>
        /*ommited for simplicity*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="xeokit_canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="treeViewContainer"></div>
</body>
<script type="module" src="./main.js">
</script>
</html>

And my main.js file looks like:
onload = async () => {

    const viewer = new Viewer({
        canvasId: "xeokit_canvas",
        transparent: true
    });

    viewer.camera.eye = [-2.56, 8.38, 8.27];
    viewer.camera.look = [13.44, 3.31, -14.83];
    viewer.camera.up = [0.10, 0.98, -0.14];

    viewer.cameraControl.panRightClick = false; // Prevents right-click-drag panning interfering with ContextMenus

    viewer.scene.xrayMaterial.fill = true;
    viewer.scene.xrayMaterial.fillAlpha = 0.1;
    viewer.scene.xrayMaterial.fillColor = [0, 0, 0];
    viewer.scene.xrayMaterial.edgeAlpha = 0.3;
    viewer.scene.xrayMaterial.edgeColor = [0, 0, 0];

    viewer.scene.highlightMaterial.fill = true;
    viewer.scene.highlightMaterial.edges = true;
    viewer.scene.highlightMaterial.fillAlpha = 0.1;
    viewer.scene.highlightMaterial.edgeAlpha = 0.1;
    viewer.scene.highlightMaterial.edgeColor = [1, 1, 0];

    viewer.scene.selectedMaterial.fill = true;
    viewer.scene.selectedMaterial.edges = true;
    viewer.scene.selectedMaterial.fillAlpha = 0.5;
    viewer.scene.selectedMaterial.edgeAlpha = 0.6;
    viewer.scene.selectedMaterial.edgeColor = [0, 1, 1];

    viewer.cameraControl.followPointer = true;


    const treeView = new TreeViewPlugin(viewer, {
        containerElement: document.getElementById("treeViewContainer"),
        autoExpandDepth: 3,
        hierarchy: "containment"
    });

    treeView.on("nodeTitleClicked", (e) => {
        const scene = viewer.scene;
        const objectIds = [];
        e.treeViewPlugin.withNodeTree(e.treeViewNode, (treeViewNode) => {
            if (treeViewNode.objectId) {
                objectIds.push(treeViewNode.objectId);
            }
        });
        e.treeViewPlugin.unShowNode();
        scene.setObjectsXRayed(scene.objectIds, true);
        scene.setObjectsVisible(scene.objectIds, true);
        scene.setObjectsXRayed(objectIds, false);
        viewer.cameraFlight.flyTo({
            aabb: scene.getAABB(objectIds),
            duration: 0.5
        }, () => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                scene.setObjectsVisible(scene.xrayedObjectIds, false);
                scene.setObjectsXRayed(scene.xrayedObjectIds, false);
            }, 500);
        });
    });

    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const src = urlParams.get("load");
    const tokens = src.split('.');
    const extension = tokens[1];

    const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoaderPlugin(viewer);
        
    gltfLoader.load({
        id: "myModel", 
        src: src,
        metaModelSrc: src.replace('glb', 'json'),
        edges: true,
        excludeUnclassifiedObjects: false
    });

    gltfLoader.on("loaded", (model) => {
        treeView.setModel(model);
    });

    window.viewer = viewer;
}

However, when I run it, I see that treeViewPanel items are not checked by default, as they should be. And if I check them, nothing happens. What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?
I tried setting model on treeView in different ways, to associate them, but it had no effect.
